# Exception : "No adapter for handler. Does your handler implement a supported interface like controller?"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to validate a simple form in JSP with Spring and Hibernate using [HibernateValidator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA-dist.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc). The JSP page Temp.jsp is as follows (the url pttern in web.xml is `*.htm`).

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<form:form method="post" action="Temp.htm" commandName="validationForm">
     <!--validationForm is a model class-->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User Name:<font color="red"><form:errors path="userName" /></font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Age:<font color="red"><form:errors path="age" /></font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Password:<font color="red"><form:errors path="password" /></font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td><form:password path="password" /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>
```

The class `validationForm` is as follows.

```
package validators;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat.Style;

final public class ValidationForm
{
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String userName;
    @NotNull
    @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
    @Min(1)
    @Max(110)
    private Integer age;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password must not be blank.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10, message = "Password must between 1 to 10 Characters.")
    private String password;

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
            this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
            return userName;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age)
    {
            this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getAge()
    {
            return age;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
            this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
            return password;
    }
}
```

and the `Controller` class where the validation should be processed is as follows (I'm using `SimpleFormController`).

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import usebeans.TempService;
import validators.ValidationForm;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
final public class Temp extends SimpleFormController 
{
    private TempService tempService=null;
    public Temp()
    {
        //setCommandClass(Temp.class);
        //setSuccessView("Temp");
        //setFormView("Temp");

        setCommandClass(ValidationForm.class); //Still not working.
        setCommandName("validationForm");
    }   

    public void setTempService(TempService tempService)
    {
        this.tempService = tempService;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
        ValidationForm validationForm=(ValidationForm) command;
        tempService.add(validationForm);
        return mv;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
        return mv;
    }
}
```

In `dispatcher-servlet`, I have added the following.

```
<bean id="tempService" class="usebeans.TempServiceImpl" />
<bean name="/Temp.htm" class="controller.Temp" p:tempService-ref="tempService" p:formView="Temp" p:successView="Temp" />
```

Also tried adding the following bean still there is no luck.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Where the `TempService` interface is as follows.

```
package usebeans;

import validators.ValidationForm;

public interface  TempService
{
    public void add(ValidationForm validationForm);
}
```

and following is the `TempServiceImpl` class.

```
package usebeans;

import validators.ValidationForm;

final public class TempServiceImpl implements TempService
{
    public void add(ValidationForm validationForm)
    {
        System.out.println("Message");
    }
}
```

Although the class `TempServiceImpl` implements the `TempService` interface, I'm getting the following exception.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [usebeans.TempServiceImpl@ab3cba]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:770)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

---

**Edit :**

Although I'm following what is explained [here](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-simple-form-controller-1.html), the problem remains and I'm getting the same exception as mentioned above. What configuration settings am I missing here. It may be in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file. The entire `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>    
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />


        <bean id="tempService" class="usebeans.TempServiceImpl" />
        <bean name="/Temp.htm" class="controller.Temp" p:tempService-ref="tempService" p:formView="Temp" p:successView="Temp" />


        <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>                
                    <prop key="Temp.htm">tempService</prop>                
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
              p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
              p:suffix=".jsp" />


        //The index controller.

        <bean name="indexController"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
              p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

I don't have any precise idea about that exception being thrown. Can you figure it out why is that exception being thrown? What configuration settings or something else am I missing here?

Comment: which version of spring is used?

Comment: The spring version is `3.0.2`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`? Can you remove this bean and try once?

Comment: @Arun, Which bean should be removed?

Comment: `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>` bean.

Comment: @Arun, it ends with an exception `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;`

Comment: `nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMap‌​ping] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMap‌​ping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMap‌​ping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue, please find the new xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />


    <bean id="tempService" class="usebeans.TempServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="tempController" class="controller.Temp"/>


    <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="Temp.htm">tempController</prop> <!-- You need to mapp the url to the controller bean-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean name="indexController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
        p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

Fix was related to `<prop key="Temp.htm">tempController</prop>`.

For the second error change the class `Temp` as below

```
package controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import usebeans.TempService;
import validators.ValidationForm;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
final public class Temp extends SimpleFormController {
    private TempService tempService = null;

    public Temp() {
        // setCommandClass(Temp.class);
        // setSuccessView("Temp");
        // setFormView("Temp");

        setCommandClass(ValidationForm.class); // Still not working.
        setCommandName("validationForm");
    }

    public void setTempService(TempService tempService) {
        this.tempService = tempService;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
            throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        ValidationForm validationForm = (ValidationForm) command;
        tempService.add(validationForm);
        return mv;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors)
            throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put(getCommandName(), new ValidationForm());
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("Temp", model);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it throws a new exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'validationForm' available as request attribute` means that the *command object* is not available to the controller. (The JSP page isn't bound to the `ValidationForm` class).

Comment: I modified the `Temp` Controller class exactly as as you mentioned but unfortunately it's throwing the same exception as mentioned in the preceding comment. The answer might be very close though.

Comment: I've not used jsp... so I don't think I can help you with the bind error problem... But you can refer this link http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-web-flow-subflow-webapp-jsp-example.html to see how it can be done.

Comment: If you can please go through spring mvc with annotation to make the spring programming easy...

Comment: We can make the spring configuration much better... I've some time constraints now... I'll try to make those changes and share with you later...